# Break string in to two from an exact position in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string that which contains a date and an index number. Simply if i enter something today and that is the 4th record.. it will go as "2015022204".
so what i need to do is break this string into two from the 8th position of the string and store both in two different strings. Can we do this without using any importing any libraries? Any easy method to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.substring` does exactly what you need.

So something like:

```
String str = "2015022204";
String date = str.substring(0, 8);
System.out.println(date);
String record = str.substring(8);
System.out.println(record);
```